# Retain checkbox value on reload not working

Tags: jquery, html

I want to retain the checked value of the check box. I have the following code. But it is not working. Can anyone correct it? I have submit button which reloads the page onClick.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/cookie.jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input.box").each(function() {
            var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
            if (mycookie && mycookie === "true") {
                $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
            }
        });

        $("input.box").change(function() {
            $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
            path: '/',
            expires: 365
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="1" value = " One ">    One<br/>
    <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="2" value = " Two ">    Two<br/>
    <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="3" value = " Three "> Three<br/>
    <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="4" value = " Four "> Four<br/>
    <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="5" value = " Five "> Five  <br/>
    <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="6" value = " Six "> Six<br/>
    <input type="Submit" value = " Submit " onClick = " javascript:window.location.reload(); ">
</body>
</html>
```

Getting the following in the console

```
    GET localhost:8080/js/… 404 (/solarether/js/cookie.jquery.js) Remember.jsp:6 
    Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'cookie'
```

Comment: `if (mycookie) {` instead of `if (mycookie && mycookie === "true") {`

Comment: make sure you get a cookie value `console.log("mycookie value::" + mycookie);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script works well in the local system. The problem you might be facing would be because of the following:

1. You are running this code in the client side.
2. The server you are running, blocks `jquery.cookie.js`, which is a recent behaviour.

Solutions:

1. Run it in a server. Some server for that case, as the URL should start with `http://`.
2. Rename `jquery.cookie.js` to some other name and include it locally!

Comment: It works for me here. I am using my localhost. First of all, did you use a server to run the code?

Comment: I am able to run it successfully on my localhost. But running it like a normal HTML file from the client side fails. :(

Comment: didn't work this way too. I am running it on TomCat 6.0

Comment: @AnushaMallajosyula May I know what did you exactly do? And also lemme know the browser and the URL you are seeing in the address bar.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code in a JSP. This is the URL I am seeing in the address bar "localhost:8080/jsp/Remember.jsp" evven after I type "http://localhost:8080/jsp/Remember.jsp"

Comment: couldnt get your comment. Can you re-comment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45632/discussion-between-anusha-mallajosyula-and-praveen-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
if (mycookie && mycookie === "true") {
    $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
}
```

If you change it so that it says `$(this).prop('checked', true)`, it should work. You match `mycookie` against a string, but the `prop()` function needs a boolean.